# Using a pinch gesture to resize a UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to let the user resize a UILabel with a pinch gesture. Using a `CGAffineTransformScale` alone doesn't do the job, because the text in the label becomes blurry when scaled up.

So what I'm doing is actually using the CGAffineTransformScale to just show that its scaling up, saving the frame size, reverting the transform identity, and finalizing the frame size. A simple switcheroo, but it works.

```
-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        startingTransform = self.transform;
    }
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){            
        CGRect endFrame = self.frame;
        self.transform = startingTransform;

        self.frame = endFrame;
    }
}
```

The end result of this is a resized frame for the UILabel. However the text does not scale up to fit the label. Also, the property adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth only works for scaling DOWNWARDS, not upwards ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel)). So what should I do to make my label scale up to fit the frame?

Answer (score 1):

You're onto something already, I think. The `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth` property will only adjust the font size *down* from whatever size it's set to... so what happens if your label's font size is set to something really big? Like vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly big compared to the possible frame size of your label?

Comment: Hmm, its an alright hack. Once you start scaling downwards though, for some reason the label text starts shifting downwards, further and further out of the height of the label. Like, so you can only see the top half of the text. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm. Might just be better to set the label's font size directly then.

Answer (score 0):

add it in scrollview and in scrollview delegzte specify the view for zooming. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/viewForZoomingInScrollView: